# Excel import from CSV by VBA from prompted location

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I try to import a csv file by VBA. The file is always called data.csv, but it can be in different folders. Therefore, this code first prompts the path, then makes *file* the file location, but there is nothing imported. What is wrong?

JV

```
Sub View()

'Prompts Path
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
Path = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

'Defining file
File = Path & "\data.csv"

Workbooks.Add

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & File, _
    Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with this code.  In my version of excel, it doesn't like using the name "Path" as a variable, so I'd probably update that.  This doesn't appear to be an issue for you however, but the second issue is that the "Range" you've used isn't defined properly.  I'm guessing it's trying to use a range in the current workbook.  It also looks like the activesheet is staying with the original workbook even when you add a new one.  Additionally, you need to refresh the querytable.  Try this:

```
Sub View()
Dim mypath As String 
Dim myfile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

'Prompts Path
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
mypath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)

'Defining file
myfile = mypath & "\data.csv"

Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
"TEXT;" & myfile, _
    Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
    .Refresh
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was probably in the set wb and ws part. The path variable is not present in my vba file, I only made it more generic to show my question.

Comment: Also, see my note about the refresh.  Without the .refresh line, the data wasn't always visible to me.